# Android: RatingBar - How to add rating to DB?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Noob here again.

I've followed the example given by Google Dev (and read a couple of other tutorials) on how to add a RatingBar to your form/app. However I have been unable to find any examples on the net, of how to take the Rating given and add it as a value to your SQLite database.

Currently you can add your own rating by simply putting a number in an EditText field. However this is not ideal, and the RatingBar seems like a more ideal solution. I suspect it has something to do with OnClick() but Im not entirely sure being a beginner.

Any ideas?

RatingBar:

```
final RatingBar ratingbar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);
        ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() { 
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                Toast.makeText(AddBook.this, "New Rating: " + rating, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

AddRow:

```
db.addRow
        (

                textFieldOne.getText().toString(),
                textFieldTwo.getText().toString(),
                textFieldThree.getText().toString(),
                textFieldFour.getText().toString(),
                textFieldFive.getText().toString(),
                textFieldSix.getText().toString()





        );

        // request the table be updated
        updateTable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you have an app.

Let's further assume that you have a user.

Let's keep going out on this limb and assume that you have an an activity in the app, in which the user will fill in data, and that the objective is for this data to wind up in a SQLite database.

Somewhere, somehow, the user has to indicate to you "Please save this data". It could be via a button, or a menu choice, or leaving the activity (e.g., `onStop()`), or whatever. I will call this the "trigger".

In your `EditText` scenario, when the trigger occurs, you would do an `insert()` or `update()` or whatever to the `SQLiteDatabase` with the contents of the `EditText`, retrieved via `getText()`.

In your `RatingBar` scenario, when the trigger occurs, you would do an `insert()` or `update()` or whatever to the `SQLiteDatabase` with the contents of the `RatingBar`, retrieved via `getRating()`.

Comment: Very Helpful. I suspected this was the case, the problem im having is with the code. I have edited to include some example code. To retriev,e would I use something like "ratingbar.getRating().toFloat()" ?

Comment: @Wrekaar: `getRating()` returns a `float`.

Comment: Tried everything and all of a sudden it now works. Turns out all I needed was wRating.getRating()

Thanks a lot, I'm chuffed its working now!